# Ordering by frequency rather than alphabetically in a set (in Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, set, counter

I was looking at an example in the Python library where the total number of occurrences of a word in a list are ordered by their frequency count in a dictionary:

```
cnt = Counter()
for word in ['red', 'blue', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'blue']:
    cnt[word] += 1
```

The output for `cnt` where the elements are listed in order of their frequency count:

```
Counter({'blue': 3, 'red': 2, 'green': 1})
```

I want to make a set where the numerical frequencies aren't included, but the order the elements are listed is retained:

```
{'blue', 'red', 'green'}
```

However in my attempt to achieve this:

```
set(word for word, count in cnt.most_common(3))
```

I instead receive a set where the elements are ordered alphabetically instead of frequency count:

```
{'blue', 'green', 'red'}
```

Is it possible to order the set according to the frequency count?

Comment: Sets aren't ordered, *at all.* If you did get alphabetic ordering then you cannot rely on it to be alphabetic next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sets are a unordered collection of unique elements, as such ordering them has no meaning whatsoever.

You probably want a list, which *is* ordered. The following uses a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to construct a list of the keys.

We can iterate over [`Counter.most_common()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) which returns a sequence of `(key, value)` tuples in order.

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter({'blue': 3, 'red': 2, 'green': 1})

keys = [key for key, val in c.most_common()]

print(keys)
# ['blue', 'red', 'green']
```

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel? `[w for w,n in c.most_common()]`

Comment: Off the top of my head I thought `most_common` didn't return all elements by default for some reason -_- Fixed anyway, thanks @tobias_k